# Is mogrify -strip a lossless operation on a TIFF in imagemagick6?

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I am still digging a weird bug that an image processed by a simple mogrify -geometry x{Height} image.tiff can have troubles loading into Python's Pillow library. The issue disappears if the mogrify operation is ran with -strip option.

I wonder if mogrify somehow generated faulty exif information as part of the operation. Is -strip considered a lossless operation as far as image data is concerned?

Comment: -strip only removes meta data. But that includes all profiles including the Adobe xmp profile. Perhaps the tiff file has some corrupt data in the xmp profile or somewhere else. But if you want to resize an image, I would not use -geometry to do that. It can behave strangely. I would replace -geometry with -resize. Also if you are only processing one image at a time, I would not use mogrify, since it has less functionality. I would recommend that you use convert rather than mogrify. What version of Imagemagick and on what platform? Can you open the original tiff in Pillow?

Comment: @fmw42 The original tiff is fine, but post mogrify on version 6.6.0 doesn't work. It seems to go away when I use version 6.9. It's a bit weird. Maybe it's due to something related to -geometry.

Comment: `@ttback`. Version 6.6.0 is exceedingly ancient (over 400 versions old) and could be problematic. If you post your exact command line, your TIFF file and your exact version of Imagemagick (6.9.x.x) and date of the version and platform, I can try to test your issue. Again, I do not suggest you use -geometry to resize images. Use -resize.